# On Hostgator, how can I remove "~username" from my website's URL?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, url

Right now to access my website I need to go to

```
http://www.example.com/~username/index.html
```

How do I remove this so I can simply type:

```
http://www.example.com/index.html
```

Right now I am FTPing into `username@0.0.0.0` (My IP)
 and putting my web source code inside `/public_html/example.co.nz`

I am using hostgator to host my website, running Windows 7 x64 bit.

Comment: Is `www.example.com` _your_ domain name (as you seem to imply), or the domain name of the shared server on which your site is just one of many?

Comment: It is my domain name.

Comment: In that case you should already be able to access `http://www.example.com/`?! What happens when you do? If you can't then it would seem that there's _something_ incorrectly configured.

Comment: http://www.example.com gives me the standard hostgator 404 page. http://www.example.com/~username/ takes me to my website

Answer (score 2):

```
http://www.example.com/~username/
```

The ~username part is a temporary URL just to open and view your website. It wont affect your website if you access it via the temporary URL. This give you the power to access the hosting files before your Domain DNS gets propagated (1 hour to 48 hours) across the globe.

```
/public_html/example.co.nz
```

This is peculiar but I have not used hostgators windows hosting yet. Normally it goes like this

```
/example.co.nz/public_html
```

Just wait a few hours before your DNS propagates and if you setup any path on your website, be sure to correct it on your script/config after the domain propagates.

Answer (score 1):

Hostgator refers to the `~username` URL as a "temporary URL."   They suggest that you don't actually use it.   Instead, you should put your domain name into your local computer's host file until it is live in DNS.

Hostgator has a [help page](https://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/temporary-url) that explains this.   It also offers migration solutions from the temporary URL for all their server configurations.

They also offer that you can contact their support team to get help with the migration.